# what does it mean by "typed objects"?

Tags: php, laravel, object, containers, typed

in the documentation of laravel for container service through this link:https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/container
below the title : "Binding Typed Variadics" you will find this :
Occasionally you may have a class that receives an array of typed objects using a variadic constructor argument.

so what is typed object?

and subsequently what is untyped object?

code:

```
class Firewall
{
protected $logger;
protected $filters;

public function __construct(Logger $logger, Filter ...$filters)
{
    $this->logger = $logger;
    $this->filters = $filters;
}
}
```

Comment: It means a parameter that is both variadic and type hinted, like `Filter ...$filters` in the example. `Filter` being a class, and `...` indicating a variadic parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since PHP is an interpreted language you have a dynamic type system. That means, that for example a sinlge variable can hold values of multiple types:

```php
$foo = "Now I'm a string";
$foo = 42; // And now I'm a number
```

Now the question becomes where the "typed objects" fit in. In [PHP Version 5 type declarations](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration.types) got introduced, because the dynamic type system imposes some problems. First and foremost you loose the ability to have [static type checking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Static_type_checking).

For example the following function can missbehave:

```php
function doSomething($a, $b)
{
  // imagine costly and long running operation here...
  return $a + $b;
}

echo doSomething(1, 2);              // -> 3
echo doSomething('hello ', 'world'); // -> Would result in an error, but only at runtime
```

To counteract type hints where introduced which the PHP interpreter can use to reason about function parameters (and return types etc.).
Additionally now that we've got types we can use a technique called [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)) to introspect what the function or rather method expects to get passed into to provide the proper objects.

**So to go full circle and answer your question:**
A typed object simply means type hinting the method parameter so laravel's service container can infer what object you'd like to be injected into your method.

```php
// not using typed objects:
class Firewall
{
  protected $logger;
  protected $filters;

  public function __construct($logger, ...$filters)
  {
    $this->logger = $logger;
    $this->filters = $filters;
  }
}

// using typed objects:
class Firewall
{
  protected $logger;
  protected $filters;

  public function __construct(Logger $logger, Filter ...$filters)
  {
    $this->logger = $logger;
    $this->filters = $filters;
  }
}
```

**Additional information:**
The reason you want to inject your dependencies rather than creating them inside your classes themselves is to obtain [inversion of control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control), preferably by injecting interfaces so you get [loose coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling) on top.

Answer (score 0):

the statement `...$filters`  means that everything else should go into the `$filters` array and the `Filter ...$filters` means every item of this array must be an instance of filter class.
so the parameter of a class witch is type hinted consider as typed object
and parameter that is not type hinted wouldn't be a typed object or its untyped object.